# What is the Time-Complexity of this function in C?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I'd like to calculate the complexity of this function in C.
It's a general tree

```
struct nodeG {  
  int key;
  struct nodeG *left_child;
  struct nodeG *right_sib;
};

int aux (NodeG u) {
    int current = 1;                                                // O(1)
    int childs = 0;                                                 // O(1)
    while (u) {                                                     // O(k)
        if (u-> left_child)                                         // O(1)
            childs += aux (u-> left_child);                         // O(1)
        if (u->right_sib && current && u->key < u->right_sib->key)  // O(1)
            current = 0;                                            // O(1)
        u = u -> right_sib;                                         // O(1)
    }
    return current + childs;                                        // O(1)
}
```

Comment: You are visiting all the nodes once, so it is _O(N)_ where N=number of nodes in the tree. And just to mention your algorithm is very similar to DFS, the condition that you use to stop the search is when you are at the null node of the current subtree so you will visit all the nodes.

Comment: You have a line of code `childs += aux (u-> left_child);`which you've commented as `// O(1)`, so it seems you've already decided the `aux` function runs in O(1) time. It doesn't, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account all the recursive calls, the function performs O(1) operations on each node in the tree, so the total runtime is O(n) where n is the number of nodes.

In more detail, the function is called once for the leftmost child of each node. The `while` loop then loops over all its siblings. So the interior of the loop is executed once per node, or a total of n times. Other than the loop and the recursive call, the remaining statements are all O(1). So this ends up taking O(n) time.

Comment: That's what I thought, but since I'm visiting exactly all the nodes of the tree, shouldn't it be Theta(n)  ?

Comment: Yes, it's Theta(n) (which of course means that it's also O(n)). Very often people will use big-O even when using theta would have been more precise.